# Create new document in .nsf file using interop.domino.dll c# specially a contact under user

Tags: c#, contacts, lotus-domino

I am trying trying to create a new contact under a specific user. My contact is created successfully but I am not able see my contact in `$Contacts View` instead of that that is exist under (Recently Archived) folder of the username.nsf file. How can create a new document under `$Contacts View`. This is the code snippet which I used to create new contact document.

```
NotesDatabase _localDatabase = _lotusNotesServerSession.GetDatabase("servername", "mail/username.nsf", false);                   

if(!_localDatabase.IsOpen)
{
    _localDatabase.Open();
}                  

NotesDocument contact = _localDatabase.CreateDocument();
contact.ReplaceItemValue("First Name","Test");
contact.ReplaceItemValue("Last Name", "Contact ");
contact.ReplaceItemValue("Mail Address", "testcontact@domain.com");
contact.ReplaceItemValue("Full Name", "Test Contact");
bool issuccess = contact.Save(true,false,false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the two views in Domino Designer, you'll see the criteria for which documents appear in each (the View Selection formula). The selection formula for ($Contacts) requires any document to have the Form field set to "Person" or "Group". You're not setting the Form field. So just add `contact.ReplaceItemValue("Form","Person")` and you'll solve the problem.

Comment: Just one thing that you should add: The items that are set in the above code are NOT the items that are expected by Notes: The documents will seem to be empty even though they contain content. Here are the real items: "First Name" must be "FirstName", "Last Name" must be "LastName", "Mail Address" needs to be "Mailaddress" and last but not least "Full Name" is called "FullName" in Notes.

Comment: Thank you Paul & Torsten for the solution. When I am implementing both of your suggestions it worked fine .

Comment: Although you've said the problem is ok now, this may help other users: when creating new documents with new fields, you may also have to set a field (NotesItem) property 'IsSummary=True' to allow the field to display in a view. Without this flag, the field will not display in a view column even if the document is selected in the view selection formula. Sometimes this property is set for you and sometimes it isn't.